# WinSCP update C# progress bar

Tags: c#, progress-bar, winscp, winscp-net

I am having issues in knowing the percentage of a file sent at any point the `FileTransferProgressEventArgs` event is fired using WinSCP .NET assembly in C#.

The `FileProgress` returns only `0` or `1`, or the documentation said (0-1) which I don't understand. I need to know how much bytes of the file is sent but not 0,1 which i don't understand. I know CPS is the bytes per second but i need more variables.

The method where i increment the progress bar is as below void

```
SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Increment((int)e.FileProgress);
}
```

Its `e.FileProgress` and `e.CPS` which I thought could help but seems I'm missing something.

Comment: What does the code of your event handler look like?

Comment: The method where i increment the progress bar is as below

void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
{
      progressBar.Increment((int)e.FileProgress);
}

its e.FileProgress and e.CPS which i thought could help but seems i'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you cast `e.FileProgress` to `int`. As you allready said, the documentation specifies that the value of `e.FileProgress` ranges from 0 to 1, for example 0.55. If you cast this value to an integer, you will lose all decimal places. So the resulting value will be 0.
To solve this problem you can transform `e.FileProgress` into a percentage value by multiplying it with 100. So you get values ranging from 0 to 100. So you can implement your event handler like so:

```
void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e) 
{
    progressBar.Value = (int)(e.FileProgress * 100);
}
```

You just have to make sure, that the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties of your progress bar are set to their default values 0 and 100.